# SQL design - consequences of creating multiple instances of the same staff member with different attributes

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-design

I need to store information for staff.  Each database instance is per parent company with multiple outlets underneath.  Some of the staff that work at an outlet can potentially also work at other outlets, however as each outlet is for the most part autonomous, each outlet will not want other outlets to see their staff list.

I wanted to create unique staff instances and just relate them to the outlets that employ them, keeping their details uniform across the database.  However my colleague wishes to allow each outlet to create their own staff members.  The consequence of this approach is that John Smith might be a staff member at outlet A, Jonathan smith at outlet B and J smith at outlet C (as each outlet could enter pretty much whatever they want).  Also each staff member has a set of skills and services associated with them, which also will not be uniform between outlets.

Will this approach cause problems down the line?  At the outlet level it probably won't make any difference, but I am concerned that if the parent group ask for reports, the results may be misleading as perhaps 5 staff members might be returned, which in reality are the same person, however may have different details.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here? Just use a uniqueidentifier for each staff member.

Comment: Basically if each outlet is free to create their own staff member, and that staff member also works at another outlet, there could be 2 or more staff members in the database that are the same person with potentially different details.  I want to know if this is just a bad idea and there would be a better way of dealing with it.

Comment: As I said, use an uniqueidentifier for each staff member (and not just their name)

Comment: Outlet A creates staff member John Smith with skills 1, 2, 3.Outlet B creates staff member J Smith (the same person) with skills 1 and 2 (they decided not to give him skill 3).  Both of these entries have a unique identifier and cannot be related to each other as their names have been entered differently, they have different skills, and they have different unique identifier.  John Smith worked at outlet A on Tuesday and outlet B on Wednesday.

Parent company wants a report of where John Smith worked in the last week.  The report won't give them the answer they are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing, if I understand you correctly, is choosing between the prospect of denormalizing a person record per outlet (giving each outlet a completely independent copy of John Smith) vs. defining a single John Smith and then defining related tables that could belong to the outlet level of access.

If you have a choice (the freedom to design the system either way) the normalized way with only 1 John Smith + auxiliary tables with outlet-specific details when necessary is the correct way.  I hesitate to say 'correct', but in the absence of very large numbers of users I would say denormalization here would only lead to avoidable integrity errors.

If you choose to denormalize now and not relate John Smith at outlet A to John Smith at outlet B even though they are in reality the same person you are both opening the door to illogical data (updates to one John and not both) and losing the ability to do simple things like count the distinct number of people in the database.

Failing to identify unique people now will prevent you from being able to properly relate other entities to a person in the future.  This will complicate your queries at the very least and give rise to logically incorrect but technically correct information in many cases.

Comment: Thank you Tahbaza, this is indeed what I meant.  I think the reason my colleague wants each outlet to be able to define their own staff is mostly from a "why should one outlet be able to define the staff member details for another outlet" sort of thing.  I basically need a good way to persuade my colleagues that normalisation is normal and that even if we can't perceive the parent company requesting that kind of data at this point, doesn't mean they won't in the future and at that point it'd be too late.  I will quote your answer to them. Thanks again

Comment: application permissions can be designed to control access to who sees and can edit the record, it need not result in multiple copies of a given person.  I usually use a "sysadmin" role to map to cross-facility edits and limit the "admin" role to single facilities (outlets).

Comment: This is only really an issue as there's no centralised control over entry into the system - even if its only the managers of each outlet that can see the staff list, it still means that they would be able to see members of staff used at other locations, and that is specifically something that we need to avoid.

Comment: You do have a dilemma there, but you don't need to give browse access to anyone at a given outlet necessarily.  If you have the concept of an employee number or other company-wide identifier to use a cross-outlet John Smith could be retrieved or even auto-associated to an existing record by that identifier.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the helpful answers (that actually answer the question), here is some useful info:

If these people are staff members (i.e. they have jobs), then why not use their social security number/national insurance number as the unique identifier? That's guaranteed to be unique and they are each guaranteed to have one.

**EDIT**: US Social Security numbers are guaranteed to be unique and are not reused. See Q20 here: http://www.ssa.gov/history/hfaq.html

EDIT: No they're not! D'oh! Thanks to Mitch Wheat for this link:  http://www.dailyfinance.com/2010/08/12/your-social-security-number-may-not-be-unique-to-you/ I guess the task is an impossible one then as there is no real way of solving the problem...

Comment: Are you saying US Social Security Numbers can be reused? Seriously?! Wow! That's ridiculously bad!

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted, all I did was give up my time to try to help somebody with some additional info. Very odd place this sometimes!

Comment: That's cool Mitch and thanks :-) I could well imagine a government system being poorly designed, so who knows?! I guess strictly speaking I wasn't answering the original question, but I thought that the info might help.

Comment: http://www.dailyfinance.com/2010/08/12/your-social-security-number-may-not-be-unique-to-you/

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the link. Incidentally, I'm in the UK so I need to go to bed about four hours ago. Laters :-)

Comment: re: social security number, i'm in the UK so could use national insurance numbers, however that won't cater for all circumstances or allow for typos. Not sure why you got down-voted either, I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

If outlets can't know the stafflist of other outlets, and outlets can add staff, there doesn't seem to be any way of preventing 2 different outlets from adding the same person, but their being recorded as different people in your system.  So unless there is some central clearinghouse, or a way for an outlet to see if a person is already listed as a staffmember (w/o getting any details about the outlet(s) she is associated with), I think you're stuck.